# How to download a large csv file from a URL with basic HTTP authentication into a data frame with R

Tags: r, csv, http, authentication, httr

I am struggling to retrieve a very large (4gb) csv file protected by basic HTTP authentication using R. I have no issue receiving the response by using the following code:

```
library(httr)
get_resp <- GET(url, authenticate(user, pass), content_type("text/csv"))
```

However when I try to call:

```
data <- content(get_resp)
```

I receive an error saying that R character strings are limited to 2^3100000 bytes or whatever. I need to get the text data into a data frame for analysis. Can anyone suggest an alternative solution?

Comment: What type of data are you trying to receive? Do you have an exampleof it?

Comment: its just a massive csv text file - a few million rows and about 300 columns. I can't share any of the actual values due to privacy concerns.

Comment: Even if I was able to grab it in chunks, that would work fine as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have the problem [describe here](https://github.com/r-lib/httr/issues/44). The suggestion was to use the `write_disk` function just to download the data and not load it into R.

Something like

```
tmp <- tempfile()
GET(url, authenticate(user, pass), content_type("text/csv"), write_disk(tmp))
paste("Data downloaded to", tmp)
```

Then you can do something else to read chunks into R or split the file before importing.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!